# Ошибка в передаче аргумента методу-члену класса. Invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++, ооп

Пишу класс дерева отрезков.
У него, конечно, есть приватное поле и публичное.

У дерева отрезков есть операция запроса суммы.
Она принимает в качестве одного из аргументов по умолчанию - приватный член класса, обозначающий размеры дерева.

И компилятор ругается на это.

> error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Tree::te' - на строке объявления переменной в private-поле.
>
> error: from this location - на строке объявления функции sum(), где мы и передаёт аргумент по-умолчанию.

Что делать?

```
class Tree {
public:
    Tree(int n) {
        tk = n;
        ts = 1;
        while(ts < tk) ts *= 2;
        te = ts * 2 - 1;

        t.resize(te, 0);
    }

void reset() {
    for(int p = ts - 1; p >= 1; p--) {
        t[p] = t[p * 2] + t[p * 2 + 1];
    }
}

void modify(int p, int x) {
    p = ts + p; t[p] = x;

    for(int i = p / 2; i >= 1; i /= 2) {
        t[i] = t[i*2] + t[i*2 + 1];
    }
}

int sum(int l, int r, int cl = 0, int cr = te, int v = 1) {
    if(cl >= r || cr <= l) return 0;
    if(cl >= l && cr <= r) return t[v];

    int mid = (cl + cr) / 2;
    return sum(l, r, cl, mid, v*2) + sum(l, r, mid, cr, v*2 + 1);
}

private:
    vector<int> t;
    int te, ts, tk;
};
```

P.s: В коде могут быть логические ошибки. Как минимум, переменную надо передавать другую в том месте. В любом случае, сейчас нас интересует ошибка компиляции, суть которой остаётся той же, что бы мы не ставили в тот аргумент по-умолчанию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Члены класса не могут использоваться в качестве аргументов по умолчанию.

Если вам это позарез нужно, то:

- Либо используйте какое-то зарезервированное значение в качестве аргумента по умолчанию, а внутри функции уже транслируйте его в то, что вам нужно

  ```
  void sum(int l, int r, int cl = 0, int cr = -1, int v = 1) {
    if (cr == -1)
      cr = te;
      ...
  ```
- Либо пользуйтесь перегрузкой для эмуляции аргументов по умолчанию

  ```
  void sum(int l, int r, int cl, int cr, int v = 1) {
    // Ваша реализация
    ...
  }

  void sum(int l, int r, int cl = 0)
  {
    sum(l, r, cl, te);
  }
  ```

Comment: Хорошо. Сделаю, как вы сказали: обёртку напишу.

Comment: Но почему нельзя? Что мешает? Для чего нужно это ограничение? В языке же ничего не бывает просто так..

Comment: @Егор Левоненко: Тут можно привести несколько причин... В частности, доступ к члену класса - это доступ через `this`. А `this` - это тоже один из параметров метода класса (это скрытый параметр метода). Таким образом мы получим, что значение аргумента по умолчанию зависит от значения другого параметра функции. А в С++ это тоже запрещено: значения аргументов по умолчанию нельзя выражать через параметры функции. Если бы это было разрешено, это бы накладывало требования на *порядок вычисления* аргументов функции при вызове. А в С++ исторически этот порядок - не определен.

Comment: То есть авторы языка не хотели вводить в спецификацию языка никакие дополнительные требования порядка вычисления аргументов функции при вызове. Аргументы вычисляются в неопределенном порядке. И поэтому в общем случае невозможно определить значение вашего умолчательного аргумента `this->te`, так как к этому моменту нет гарантии, что уже вычислено значение `this`.

Comment: Спасибо. Впрочем, всё равно они могли бы предусмотреть такое. Всё-таки, язык должен быть инструментом, а не объектом для исследований..) Всё-таки, если аргумент this - скрытый, почему бы не делать его обрабатываемым в самую первую очередь? Совсем непонятно.. Наверное, у них всё-таки был какой-то мотив не добавлять в спецификацию ещё правил.)